# Traer rama tal cual esta en remoto y descartar cambios de local

Tags: git

Quiero traer una rama exactamente igual a como esta en remoto y que los cambios que yo haya hecho en esa rama localmente queden descartados, Cuál sería el procedimiento adecuado a realizar?

Answer (score 0):

[Mira este post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125968/how-do-i-force-git-pull-to-overwrite-local-files)

La idea es forzar un reset de los documentos y cambios locales:

```
git stash --include-untracked
git reset --hard
git clean -fd
```

Luego volver a hacer otro pull:

```
git pull
```